# Could not send email in django rest framework

Tags: django, email

I am developing password reset part of the project. I am using `django_rest_passwordreset` to get the password reset. I am using mailjet smtp. I could not send the email to the user.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'in-v3.mailjet.com'
# EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '5e4329460b3c88f1d24d19c3e7374548aa213da%asasd1asd'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'a6c5ab2515d6ae761253a396453530ba$42asasdasdaasdasd'
```

If I change the `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` to the `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` it is printing it to the console. I have no idea why it is not working.

the part of the code where I am trying to send an email.

```
@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):
    # send an e-mail to the user
    context = {
        'current_user': reset_password_token.user,
        'username': reset_password_token.user.firstname,
        'email': reset_password_token.user.email,
        'reset_password_url': "{}?token={}".format(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-request'), reset_password_token.key)
    }
    # just checking if it works
    send_mail('Hello from something', 'hello there', 'abdukhashimov@yandex.ru',
              [reset_password_token.user.email, ], fail_silently=False)
    # render email text
    email_html_message = render_to_string('user_reset_password.html', context)
    email_plaintext_message = render_to_string(
        'user_reset_password.txt', context)

    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        # title:
        "Password Reset for {title}".format(title="Some website title"),
        # message:
        email_plaintext_message,
        # from:
        "noreply@somehost.local",
        # to:
        [reset_password_token.user.email]
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(email_html_message, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a different solution. I used the google smtp service. I have followed the steps from this [kinsta.com - steps to setup up google smtp](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/free-smtp-server/).

**Step1:** The very first thing you will need to do is ensure that you have 2-step verification enabled on your primary Gmail account. Important: If you don’t do this you will get an invalid password error further below when trying to authenticate your email address. So first go and enable 2-step verification.

**Step2:** Next, you will need to generate an App password. You then use the app password in place of your personal Gmail password further below. This is the only way this process will work.

**Step3:** Now back in Gmail, go to settings, and can click on “Accounts and Import.” Then click on “Add another email address you own.”. Basically to the gmail and sign in with your account and go to the settings.

**Step4:** Enter your additional business name and business email that is on the custom domain.

[image: An image from kinsta.com showing how to add another email account]
(Extra Info). I usually use yandex mail and added it then it generated the followings.

[image: My generated information]

**Step5:** It will then send an email confirmation code to the email you just added. You will need to click the link in the email to confirm it or manually enter the code (this proves that you are in fact the owner of the additional email account). And that’s it!

From my experience, you might need to tweak some settings from google if it did not work for you. For example, I read from other source, you might need to allow less secure apps from google. I have not done it as I was using yandex mail, I guess.

In case if you are not sure what to put in `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru' # in my case
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'added account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your password'
```

Credits to [kinsta.com](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/free-smtp-server/)